# Make magic link descriptions less ambiguous

Tags: feature-request, help-center, magic-links

Currently, all the help center magic links have the same text: "help center". This isn't helpful. There's a big difference between `[help/dont-ask]` and `[help/behavior]` or `[meta-help]`.

Could we make the text the title of the page instead?

(Ideally without retroactively affecting older ones, though as it looks like the expansion happens at rendering time, which for comments is just about whenever the page is served, that would seem to involve a special case based on the date/time of the comment, which is yucky.)

---

*(Re "magic links", see [this](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238) and [this](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).)*

Comment: Wow, I was trying to figure out how to suggest exactly this only a few days ago. Thanks for doing that! +1 I'd like this, I often _don't use_ these links because the fact they just say 'help center' is unhelpful and forces me to phrase things strangely. This site strictly adheres to meaningful link names; this is the only instance I know of that is the opposite.